How to setup npm for private registry
I have company managed private npm registry (in nexus) secured with ssl cert. I can access it through browser, also with curl with my personal cert.
For example this is working, I can get a package content, so I guess my certificates are ok:
curl -vvv https://example.com/repository/group/example-package --cert my.crt --key my.key

But when I use npm i I end with error
npm i example-package --registry https://example.com/repository/group/ --certfile=my.crt --keyfile=my.key --verbose --strict-ssl=true

errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
This is quite famous error, most of answers is to set strict-ssl to false, but with this option I get.
npm http fetch GET 401  https://example.com/repository/group/example-package 318ms (cache skip)
...
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized 

I tried all combinations of parameters which can be used with this (--cafile, --certfile, --keyfile) but always the same result. Am I missing something?

It seems one working solution is to use .npmrc and prefix URI fragment to certificate variables (URL without https:// part ).
.npmrc
registry=https://example.com/repository/group/
//example.com/repository/group/:keyfile=/absolute/path/to/my.key
//example.com/repository/group/:certfile=/absolute/path/to/my.crt

Now simple npm i <package_name> working, no need for --strict-ssl=false or setting NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED or NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS env variables (popular workarounds for ssl problems).
Another option is to use npm config (URI fragment prefix still required). Keep in mind npm doesn't throw any error if URI prefix is invalid or crt file doesn't exists (or path is invalid).
npm config set //example.com/repository/group/:keyfile=/absolute/path/to/my.key
npm config set //example.com/repository/group/:certfile=/absolute/path/to/my.cert

.npmrc docs
npm config docs
